# add-apt-repository: Problem with the SSL CA cert

Tags: python, ssl, add-apt-repository, python-2.7

```
user@amd64:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
[sudo] password for 1: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (77, 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)')
```

### How to fix that?

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pycurl/+bug/926548
- is this bug related?

My system:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 amd64
python 2.7.3-0ubuntu2
python-software-properties 0.82.7
python-pycurl 7.19.0-4ubuntu3
libgnutls26 2.12.14-5ubuntu3
```

I also tried to install python-software-properties 0.82.7.1 and libgnutls26 2.12.14-5ubuntu3.1 from precise-updates, but it did not help =(

Answer (score 3):

Nobody helped me =( But I found solution: reinstall package "ca-certificates" helped me))

Thanks to this log =)
http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/05/26/%23kubuntu-devel.html

Comment: Please edit your answer to include essential parts of the answer from the link you specified, then accept your answer to mark this as solved. Thank you.

Comment: You appear to have two user accounts. Get your accounts merged and you will be able to accept the answer. http://askubuntu.com/contact/user-merge

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've CA certificates to allow SSL-based applications to check for the authenticity of SSL connections. They can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates openssl
```

If you have it, consider reinstalling it (replace `install` with `reinstall`).

You can also try running: `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Related:

- [cURL not working (Error #77) for SSL connections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55859036/55075)
- [curl: (77) pbm with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269614/21471)